# App which can execute arbitrary code on different events

Tags: command-line, cron, inotify

I've been looking for a simple *activator* which can execute some code when *stuff* happens, I haven't found anything yet. Maybe, I am not using the right keywords. It would be great if someone pointed me to the right app.

These are the things I am looking for, in the activator:

- An event should be able to trigger an arbitrary chunk of code
- An event can be

  - a datetime, or a datetime match expression. (time: '16:00', day: 'monday' or day: 'monday', month: 'jan' etc,.)
  - a message on a socket?
  - anything written out to a device like /dev/*
  - a file creation, maybe in a special directory

If there is nothing which does this, would someone be interested in something like this?

A very basic configuration(written in ruby) for this would be:

```
trigger_when({:day => 6, :time => '10:30'}, {:message => 'Awesome message'}) # :day => 6 for sunday
trigger_when({:day => 0, :time => '10:30'}) do
  puts 'awesome stuff happens'
end
```

I have created a [repo github hoping to create something like this](https://github.com/minhajuddin/activator/blob/master/activator) , but it would be great if there is an existing app which does this.

There is an android app which seems to do almost the exact thing http://tasker.dinglisch.net/. I am looking for something which does it on a desktop.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of tools that do *something* like this, though not necessarily all of the above.  For example, Apple's `launchd` will handle your time-of-day requirements as well as socket connections and monitored directories.  The [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) program can respond to arbitrary events, although it generally expects the events to be generated by external programs (such as udev).

There are a number of tools (such as `incron`) that can respond to filesystem events.

You can probably mix-and-match to get what you want.

Comment: libevent http://linux.die.net/man/3/event event api  to execute a function when a specific event on a file descriptor occurs or after a given time has passed.

Comment: upstart would be perfect for my needs but it needs super user permissions to emit events, and it doesn't allow stuff to be executed at a certain time, It's on their todo list.

Comment: I think [AnyEvent](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/AnyEvent-6.11/lib/AnyEvent/Intro.pod#What_is_AnyEvent?) is of interest here, too; it's a Perl module.